# Using Plink to script commands to Dell PowerConnect 6224

Tags: switch, putty, dell-powerconnect

I'm trying to setup a simple script to update the configuration on a Dell PowerConnect 6224. I have SSH setup and working and can connect to the switch using either Putty or PLink but when I use plink's -m option to specify the file containing the commands I get a "packet integrity error".

Plink will connect fine without the -m option, or with an empty command file, but as soon as I add a command (eg. "quit") to the file it fails.

Has anyone had any luck scripting commands to these switches?

The full -v output is:

> Looking up host "192.168.100.2"
>   Connecting to 192.168.100.2 port 22
>   Server version: SSH-1.99-OpenSSH_4.3
>   We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.60
>   Using SSH protocol version 2
>   Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange
>   Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-1
>   Host key fingerprint is:
>   ssh-rsa 1024 97:e5:8e:d6:a5:0d:b0:a6:96:78:be:93:e3:57:79:d4
>   Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
>   Initialised HMAC-SHA1 client->server MAC algorithm
>   Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
>   Initialised HMAC-SHA1 server->client MAC algorithm
>   Using username "test-user".
>   Keyboard-interactive authentication refused
>   Sent password
>   Access granted
>   Opened channel for session
>   Received disconnect message (protocol error)
>   Disconnection message text: Packet integrity error.
>   Server sent disconnect message
>   type 2 (protocol error):
>   "Packet integrity error."
>   FATAL ERROR: Server sent disconnect message
>   type 2 (protocol error):
>   "Packet integrity error."